# Octopus Deploy queue doesn't pick up new tasks

Tags: octopus-deploy

Since the last 2 weeks Octopus Deploy doesn't pick up new tasks. In the server logs I discovered this log multiple times:

> Outstanding health checks for the machine policy Default Machine Policy were not completed before the next task was due to be scheduled. If this error persists, check the Tasks tab for any running health check tasks, and cancel them manually.

I've deleted the health check task manually, but this doesn't solve the problem. I restarted the Tentacle service: but still no luck.... how can I resolve this?

Comment: Is there any other task active in the `ServerTask` table?

Comment: There were no other running tasks in the task table besides the pending health check tasks. I cancelled these pending tasks which doesn't solve these problems.  Finally, I restarted the Octpus Server service which solved my problem.

Comment: Using the Octopus manager to restart didn't fix the same issue for us.  Restarting the box did.  Strange.  Issue arose after patching and rebooting.  Maybe the box and service didn't come up correctly.